# Unable to Configure listener In Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, listener

I have installed Oracle 11g but not able to configure listener. I used Net Configuration Assistant and configured it succesfully but when I click finish all configuration gets lost.

When I start Net Configuration again then I need to do same steps again and same result. It does not show delete,rename options.

Comment: are you running the configuration wizard as admin ?

Comment: hope so as i have already given oracle Administrative privilege anyways let me confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly Mistake. Yes It was not running using Administrator. Right Click and run as Administrator simply solved it.